# Making a script bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make script bookmarklet that autofills a form into a website, the script that I made based on google search worked after some modification but it works only in the console.

```
$($0 || 'body').find('input, textarea, select').filter(':visible').each(function(){

if( $(this).attr('id')==='email' || $(this).attr('name')==='email' )
    return $(this).val('some@email.com');

if( $(this).attr('id')==='phone' || $(this).attr('name')==='phone' )
    return $(this).val('PHONE NUMBER');

if( $(this).attr('id')==='juridiction' || $(this).attr('name')==='juridiction' )
    return $(this).val('JURIDICTION');            });
```

Can someone explain to me it should be done.

Comment: If the web site you are trying to run this does not have jQuery, this has no way of working. Any errors in console after you try to run it?

Comment: The website does have jQuery, and in the console it worked.

Comment: It works only in console, but Im looking to make it a bookmarklet to launch byt one simple click in the browser

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `encodeURIComponent` function in JavaScript to properly encode any function. There are also websites to do this. To make a bookmarklet, you'd just prepend `javascript:` to your encoded script.

Simple example:

1. Your function: `alert('hello!');`
2. ...encoded `alert('hello!')%3B`
3. ...now a URL: `javascript:alert('hello!')%3B`

(Note that step 2 was generated by running `encodeURIComponent("alert('hello!');")` in the browser console.)

Try it yourself by pasting the last step directly into the address bar of your browser. (You may have to retype `javascript:`, browsers seem to trim that off when you perform a paste, probably as a security measure.)

If you follow the exact same steps on the code snippet you provided, you should get the following:

```
javascript:%24(%240%20%7C%7C%20'body').find('input%2C%20textarea%2C%20select').filter('%3Avisible').each(function()%7B%0A%0Aif(%20%24(this).attr('id')%3D%3D%3D'email'%20%7C%7C%20%24(this).attr('name')%3D%3D%3D'email'%20)%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%24(this).val('some%40email.com')%3B%0A%0Aif(%20%24(this).attr('id')%3D%3D%3D'phone'%20%7C%7C%20%24(this).attr('name')%3D%3D%3D'phone'%20)%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%24(this).val('PHONE%20NUMBER')%3B%0A%0Aif(%20%24(this).attr('id')%3D%3D%3D'juridiction'%20%7C%7C%20%24(this).attr('name')%3D%3D%3D'juridiction'%20)%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%24(this).val('JURIDICTION')%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B
```

You can now create a new bookmark and paste in that URL. Voila! A bookmarklet. Any errors will be logged in your browser console.

**EDIT**

Bonus tip: to easily encode multiline functions in the console, use a relatively new feature (since ES6) called [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Example:

```
encodeURIComponent(`
  alert('Line 1!');
  alert('Line 2!');
`);
```

This wouldn't be possible with your typical quotes.